# jQuery Ajax to axios; parameters cut off

Tags: jquery, forms, api, axios

How can I convert this code to axios

```js
var username = document.getElementById('id_username').value;
var password = document.getElementById('id_password').value;

$.ajax({
  type: "get",
  url: "/accounts/validate_credentials_ajax/",
  data: {
    username: username,
    password: password,
  },
  dataType: "json",
  success: function(data) {
    if (data == false) {
      usernameError.innerHTML =
        "Please enter a correct username and password. Note that both fields may be case-sensitive.";
    } else {
      usernameError.innerHTML = "";
      document.getElementById("loginForm").submit();
    }
  },
});
```

I tried to do this:

```js
axios('/accounts/validate_credentials_ajax/' + '?username=' + username + '&' + 'password=' + password)
  .then(function(data) {
    console.log(data)
  })
```

but it doesn't take the whole value of the password. Example if I type 'hellostackoverflow' it sends something like 'hellostackover'. But the username is sent correctly. Someone please help.

Comment: `axios("url", { params: { username: ..., password: ... } })`

Comment: _"if I type 'hellostackoverflow' it sends something like 'hellostackover'"_ - You will get better help when you add an actual password that gets truncated (because it might be related to the missing `encodeURIComponent()` calls).